# Unable to publish LUIS App

Tags: artificial-intelligence, publish, azure-language-understanding

We are unable to publish the LUIS application. Publish button was disabled. Please find the attached screenshot and suggest on this please. 
[image]

Comment: Please add the image to the post itself (no external link), and give a description of your current setup. Hard to guess what went wrong without additional info.

Comment: does the wait solved this problem ? I am still seeing disabled buttons .

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem in the afternoons (UK) - wait a few hours and it's fine. I wonder if the system gets overloaded at times.

Answer (score 0):

The reason was session time out.  I looked at console and found `400` error which says `token is missing`.  So  i signed out and signed back in. It started working. I was able to publish code to any slot specified.

It looks like a bug and microsoft should address this session timeout with auto redirect or a proper message.

Answer (score 0):

Try Browsing/Publishing in Incognito mode / Private Browsing.
There are Caching related issue in luis portal

Answer (score 0):

Every day at about 18:30 GMT we get lots of timeouts and 503 and publishing problems. We decided not to publish during that time.

Today we got more delays than usual

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/ show no errors in westus (the endpoint we are reaching)
It'd very nice to get a LUIS Status page (and not the global Cognitive Status)

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been around for a while now. Advice from Microsoft support was to:

- delete all cookies for luis.ai
- sign out of the session
- then sign back
  in

When you sign in again the publish to production button should be enabled again